# SPSS Modeler - Date Function fpr lastweek

Tags: date, datetime, spss, spss-modeler

I wanted to know if it was possible  to use a date function for last week's date ranges. Currently I'm using the method as below.
Thanks.

```
   datetime_date('Sale.Date') >= datetime_date(2016,04,18)
  and 
   datetime_date('Sale.Date') <= datetime_date(2016,04,24)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a great solution but:

--datetime_date(datetime_year(@TODAY), datetime_month(@TODAY), datetime_day(@TODAY)-7)

This will work for all but 7 days of the month.

You could also get a rough estimate by calculating the following (note that you will use the method I outline and not the equations. you must copy paste the equations into their designated locations).

--a=date_in_years(@TODAY)-7/365

--year=a-(a mod 1)+1900

--month=(a mod 1)-((a mod 1) mod 1/12) *12

etc. then entering these formulas into this formula:

--datetime_date(year,month,day)

OR you can use SQL to calculate a 7 day difference. This will be the accurate and easy but would require the correct setup.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you are looking for exactly; what do you mean by "last week"? Is that the 7 days prior to today or is it the last calendar week? If it's the calendar week, which definition are you using? What day of the week does a week start? When does the first week of the year start?
Unfortunately, these definition vary between different parts of the world and even for different uses within countries.

Dates in SPSS Modeler are all represented as the number of seconds from Jan. 1st, 1900, so if you are looking for the dates of the past 7 days, the calculations are fairly trivial as you can use the `datetime_in_seconds()` function to get the numeric representation of any date or timestamp.

If you are looking for calendar weeks, things get a little more complicated, but I should be able to help with that, too, if you can answer the above questions.

Answer (score 0):

For SPSS Modeler you can use a Derive Node and I see two options to do that:

*A)
Derive Node: date_weeks_difference(date1,date2)
And then use a Filter node to keep only the derive node = 1*

*B)
Or you can use a function inside the Derive Node, creating a dummy variable:
if date_weeks_difference(date1,date2)= 1 then 1 else 0 endif*